# How to make an expression manifestly symmetric

Tags: summation, symmetry

Believe it or not, the following expression is symmetric under the exchange of the indices $j$ and $k$, i.e. $R_{kj}=R_{jk}$:
$$
R_{jk}=j s_js_k-\sum_{n=1}^{\min(N-k,j)}(k-j+2n)s_{j-n}s_{k+n}
$$
Where $1\leq j\leq N$ and $1\leq k\leq N$. The symmetry is far from obvious to me. Is there a way of rewriting an expression like this into a manifestly symmetric form?

EDIT: I know $R_{jk}$ is symmetric, I don't need to prove it. Moreover, the symmetrization "by force" (i.e. writing $R_{jk}=\frac12(R_{jk}+R_{kj})$) does not seem to give me a simpler formula, but I might just not be doing it right...

Answer (score 0):

Let $s=k+j,d=k-j$, then we want to show that $R_{s,d}=R_{s,-d}$
Let $P_{s,d}=s_js_k=s_ks_j=P_{s,-d}$
$k=\frac{s+d}{2},j=\frac{s-d}{2}$, let $m=(d/2)+n$ 
$$R_{s,d}=\frac{s-d}{2}P_{s,d}-\sum_{m=\frac{d}{2}+1}^{\min(N-s/2,s/2)}2mP_{s,2m}$$
Replace $d$ by $-d$, 
$$R_{s,-d}=\frac{s+d}{2}P_{s,-d}-\sum_{m=-\frac{d}{2}+1}^{\min(N-s/2,s/2)}2mP_{s,2m}$$
$$R_{s,-d}-R_{s,d}=dP_{s,d}-\sum_{m=-\frac{d}{2}+1}^{\frac{d}{2}}2mP_{s,2m}$$
By symmetry about zero, most terms in the sum cancel, leaving just the $m=d/2$ term,  $dP_{s,d}$

Comment: Shouldn't the result be zero if $R_{s,d}=R_{s,-d}$? Also, when you send $d$ to $-d$, why isn't $m$ changing in the sum?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant zero.  $m$ is the dummy variable, so $d$ only appears below the $\Sigma$ as one end of the $m$ values.  In one case, $m$ ranges from $d/2+1$ to $\min(...)$, and in the other case from $-d/2+1$ to $\min(...)$.  The difference is $m$ ranges from $-d/2+1$ to $d/2$.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, thanks for the clarification. However, this is a proof that $R_{ij}$ is symmetric. I knew that already, what I need is to rewrite it in a manifestly symmetric form.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do this: define

$$ \tilde{R}_{jk} = \frac{1}{2}\left( R_{jk} + R_{kj} \right) $$

Then $\tilde{R}_{jk}$ is manifestly symmetric. And if $R_{jk}$ truly is symmetric too, then you will have $R_{jk} = \tilde{R}_{jk}$.

A common way to prove that $R_{jk}$ is symmetric is to compute its *antisymmetric* part:

$$ \hat{R}_{jk} = \frac{1}{2}\left( R_{jk} - R_{kj} \right) $$

and show that $\hat{R}_{jk} = 0$.

($\tilde{R}$ and $\hat{R}$ are just decorations I've added for the purposes of this answer; they are not standard notations for the symmetrization and antisymmetrization of $R$)

Comment: I already know it is symmetric, I don't need to prove it again. I have been trying exactly this strategy all night (symmetrizing "by force"), but I don't obtain a simpler expression, one that I can look at and see only occurrences of $i+j$ and $s_is_j$, say. The upper limit of the sum is what throws me off the most...